# Why is a job in the second stage of my Gitlab pipeline being executed despite a previous job in the first stage failing?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm running a pipeline on Gitlab with 2 stages. On the first stage there are 2 jobs of which one has `allow_failure: true`. This works, because it fails and I see an orange exclamation mark. The other one fails too and I get a red cross.

The second stage has 1 job that should not be executed, because a task that may not fail, failed. It is still executed. What am I doing wrong? I was in the understanding that, by default, a job from a second, third, etc stage would never be executed (manually or automatically) until all previous stages have been 100% successful (unless a certain task is allowed to fail).

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
    - stage1
    - stage2

job1:
    stage: stage1
    script:
        - <something>
    allow_failure: true

job2:
    stage: stage1
    script:
        - <something>

job3:
    stage: stage2
    script:
        - <something>
```

Answer (score 0):

You understand right, if job2 fails, the next stage shouldn't run, see the example in the documentation, it is basically the same as your yaml https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure

Since your gitlab-ci.yml is obviously a simplified version, I don't see anything that goes wrong here but maybe there's something you left out that affects this. Is job2 a manual job? does job2 extend other jobs that maybe have "allow_failure: true"? I suggest adding "allow_failure: false" to job2.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It was an oversimplification and the issue turned out to be that job3 had a `needs`. See for more information: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/32598